# How to copy rows in new worksheets based on a value of a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to create the following macro, but I failed:

I have Sheet1 with several columns, one of them is named "Serial Number"
I want the macro to add 5 new worksheets, named "Customer1"..."Customer5"
Then to go through the column named "Serial Number" and if the number is one of group numbers for each customer to copy/paste the row in the respective worksheet.
The serial numbers for the different customers are groups of 5 or 6 digits, but not consecutive so I must put them manually (for example **if 1234 or 2345 or 7654.... -> copy/paste to Customer1**).

I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: What have you got so far for your macro?

Comment: I tried to modify an example from here, but got lost (receiving errors and not understanding most of it). I started to read about macros a couple of days ago just to complete this task.

Comment: How do you determine which customer number a given serial number belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, not performant but gets the job done:

```
Sub go_through_rows ()
lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
for i to lastrow
IF Cells(i,1) = "cutomer ID" OR "cutomer ID2" 'If your customer ID is in row A , if it's in B use 2 instead of 1 here and so on
rows(i & ":" & i).select
selection.copy
SHEETS("target sheet name").activate
CELLS("A1").select
SELECTION.End(XlDOWN).select 'jumps to the last value in the sheet make sure there is data here already
ActiveCell.OFFSET(1, 0).select
Paste
Sheets("sheet with the raw data").activate
ELSE 'nothing
END IF
next i
```

This can be adapted by more IFs and adding the values as variables.
Should work for your purpose, but as said, it's not very performant if your data is huge.

Comment: I will try it soon and will come back with a feedback. Thanks for now!